# ssh-copy-id: why is the end of my public key different on my local vs remote?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Usually in the past I've always manually copied over my SSH public key to the remotes where necessary. I'm on a Mac and I finally decided to start using *ssh-copy-id* to make my life simpler, so I just used homebrew to install it.

I just used *ssh-copy-id* for the first time and am little confused by the result.

On my local machine, when viewing my *id_rsa.pub* key, it ends with *username@machinename*. I love this and it's made it easy to identify keys I can delete on remote machines later on.

I just used *ssh-copy-id* on my local machine to move my public key to a remote and then took a look at the *authorized_keys* file on the remote. I noticed that on the remote instead of my public key ending with *myusername@mymachinename* (as expected) it now ends with */Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa* ??

Why the discrepancy? Is there any way to force ssh-copy-id to use *username@machinename* like it does on my local machine?

This might just be a misunderstanding I have with SSH and keys in general, but any thoughts are appreciated?

**EDIT**:

Just discovered that this only happens when I exclude my identity file and assume defaults.

Basically if I only do: *ssh-copy-id user@hostname* then I get this awkward comment in the *authorized_keys* file on the remote.

If I specify my public key: *ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@hostname* then everything copies over as expected, using *myusername@machinename* as expected ?!

What's causing this oddity? The following link says that it should always default to using my *id_rsa.pub* file anyway, so I shouldn't need to specify it to get the right comment on the remote should I? http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add option `-i` when running `ssh-copy-id`.  This is explained in the manual:

```
 Default behaviour without -i, is to check if 'ssh-add -L' provides any
 output, and if so those keys are used.  Note that this results in the
 comment on the key being the filename that was given to ssh-add(1) when
 the key was loaded into your ssh-agent(1) rather than the comment con-
 tained in that file, which is a bit of a shame.  Otherwise, if ssh-add(1)
 provides no keys contents of the default_ID_file will be used.
```